# Issues with creating json and/or xml

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, xml, dictionary

I need help with writing code in python, I need to write a code that either create a json or xml with the words' position/index in the sentence, whether or not all the characters in the word are alphabet letters and finally the word itself for each word in the sentence they provide me. I first thought about using a simple dictionary to store the key and values and then transform the dictionary into json:

```
import json
data = {}
liste = [] # it's for storing all the words after splitting them by space
sentence="As its price tag has been slashed to $1.7trn over a decade, half as much as first pitched, the hunger—or squid—games between progressives and moderates have turned fiercer."

liste = sentence.split(" ")
for word,index in zip(liste,range(0,len(liste))):
    data[word.lower()] = {"alpha":word.lower().isalpha()}
    data[word.lower()]['Word'] = word.lower()
    data[word.lower()]['Index'] = index
json_data = json.dumps(data,ensure_ascii=False)
print(json_data)
```

which prints me this json:

```
{"as": {"alpha": true, "Word": "as", "Number": 15}, "its": {"alpha": true, "Word": "its", "Number": 1}, "price": {"alpha": true, "Word": "price", "Number": 2}, "tag": {"alpha": true, "Word": "tag", "Number": 3}, "has": {"alpha": true, "Word": "has", "Number": 4}, "been": {"alpha": true, "Word": "been", "Number": 5}, "slashed": {"alpha": true, "Word": "slashed", "Number": 6}, "to": {"alpha": true, "Word": "to", "Number": 7}, "$1.7trn": {"alpha": false, "Word": "$1.7trn", "Number": 8}, "over": {"alpha": true, "Word": "over", "Number": 9}, "a": {"alpha": true, "Word": "a", "Number": 10}, "decade,": {"alpha": false, "Word": "decade,", "Number": 11}, "half": {"alpha": true, "Word": "half", "Number": 12}, "much": {"alpha": true, "Word": "much", "Number":14}, "first": {"alpha": true, "Word": "first", "Number": 16}, "pitched,": {"alpha": false, "Word": "pitched,", "Number": 17}, "the": {"alpha": true, "Word": "the", "Number": 18}, "hunger—or": {"alpha": false, "Word": "hunger—or", "Number": 19}, "squid—games": {"alpha": false, "Word": "squid—games", "Number": 20}, "between": {"alpha": true, "Word": "between", "Number": 21}, "progressives": {"alpha": true, "Word": "progressives", "Number": 22}, "and": {"alpha": true, "Word": "and", "Number": 23}, "moderates": {"alpha": true, "Word": "moderates", "Number": 24}, "have": {"alpha": true, "Word": "have", "Number": 25}, "turned": {"alpha": true, "Word": "turned", "Number": 26}, "fiercer.": {"alpha": false, "Word": "fiercer.", "Number": 27}}
```

As you can see this json is not correct, there are some words that are missing (the two other "as"). After doing some research on stackoverflow, I think that I start to understand why: If my understanding is correct, a dictionary and a json object cannot have the same key more than once. But the problem is that in most english sentences some words are repeated.

Example of an english sentence: As its price tag has been slashed to $1.7trn over a decade, half as much as first pitched, the hunger—or squid—games between progressives and moderates have turned fiercer.

In this sentence the word "as" is repeated 3 times, so I think in my code the key in the dictionary got overwritten twice, as there are 3  words "as". Is my thinking correct? If it's right, what can I do to solve this problem? Can I bypass the unique key of dictionary or json problem somehow? Which data structure should I use and how to get either a json or xml as output?

Comment: You might look into `collections.defaultdict` or `collections.Counter`.

Comment: Thank you @oc11, this is what i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

In json you cannot bypass this syntax-wise, however you could just add a json attribute to a word that would be its occurences:

```py
data[word.lower()]["occurences"]= data[word.lower()]["occurences"] +1 if word.lower() in data else 1
```

As a sidenote, I would strongly advise you to rename frequently used code as an attribute (here at the very least `word.lower()`)